# Making a SQL Function that Allows Users to Pick and Entry for an Online Survey

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a website. I need to make a customer survey, so I'm working on a SQL database that allows Users to pick from a list of options. The survey will be displayed as a popup on a page using PHP. I'm having trouble making the column that contains the list of options.

```
USE survey; 
CREATE TABLE questionnaire 
(
firstName VARCHAR(255), 
email VARCHAR(255), 
reference VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT ck_YourConstraint CHECK (reference = 'Socials' OR reference = 'Google search' OR reference = 'Google Mybusiness' OR reference = 'Referal' OR reference = 'Email') ;
```

```
CREATE DATABASE customer_survey;  
USE customer_survey, 

CREATE TABLE questionnaire (
firstName VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
reference VARCHAR(255) VALUES 
('Socials', 'Google search', 'Google Mybusiness', 'Referal', 'Email')); 

USE customer_survey 
CREATE TABLE answers 
INSERT INTO answers ('FirstName' Not Null, 'email' Not Null, 'Socials', 'Google search', 'Google Mybusiness', 'Referal', 'Email'));
```

Comment: Normally you would create two tables for this: A table to hold the questions and a table to hold the options. The options table has a column that tells you to which question an option belongs. Two more tables are probably needed: One for the users of the survey and one for the answers they give. The answers table would, at least, have three columns, referencing the question that was answered, which option was chosen, and the user that answered the question. That's four tables already, where you try to squeeze everything into one.

Comment: Also one could reasonably assume that one day there will be another survey, for a different purpose, with different questions, different options and of course different users providing different answers. So you may also need a surveys table, then the questions table that FK's to surveys, and the options table that FK's to questions and so on.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware. Thanks for responding. I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/36a7ea97-baaf-450a-9967-8a1a3477b7bf/sql-dealing-with-multiple-choice-answers-in-a-db-with-no-unique-identifier?forum=transactsql. It gives instructions on how to put the questions and answers in separate tables. I will go through this and rework the code.

Comment: I created 2 tables, one for the question and one for the answers. It looks like this: CREATE DATABASE customer_survey;  
USE customer_survey, 

CREATE TABLE questionnaire (
firstName VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
reference VARCHAR(255) VALUES 
('Socials', 'Google search', 'Google Mybusiness', 'Referal', 'Email')); 

USE customer_survey 
CREATE TABLE answers 
INSERT INTO answers ('FirstName' Not Null, 'email' Not Null, 'Socials', 'Google search', 'Google Mybusiness', 'Referal', 'Email'));